On StateHasChanged(), the language culture reverts to the default language (Blazor)
I implemented two languages to the Blazor Application, in which I have a CultureSelector (selecting languages) and a CultureController which sets the culture as a cookie. I also use IStringLocalizer with resource files to map each of these. This works, until my razor page called "DevicePage.razor" gets data through a stream that looks something like this:
 stream = await StreamSubscriber<DeviceStateEntry>.CreateAsync(clusterClient, "facility", FacilityId, async (entry) =>
 {

     
     if (entry.FacilityId == FacilityId)
     {
         await InvokeAsync(() =>
     {

         if (!Devices.ContainsKey(entry.Id))
         {
             return;
         }
         else
         {
             Devices[entry.Id].Entries.Add(entry);
             StateHasChanged();
             
         }

     });

Whenever the StateHasChanged() is run, it looks almost like the UI is flickering between the new language and to the default language (and sometimes straight to the key of the resource files used).
My CultureController:
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class CultureController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Set(string culture, string redirectUri)
    {
        if (culture != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
                    new RequestCulture(culture, culture)));
        }

        return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
    }
}

CultureSelector:
<MudStack>
    <MudSelect Value="selectedCulture" T="CultureInfo" ValueChanged="OnCultureChanged">
        <MudSelectItem T="CultureInfo" Value="supportedCultures[0]">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom_%283-5%29.svg" height="14" class="mr-1" />English
        </MudSelectItem>

        <MudSelectItem Value="supportedCultures[1]">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg" height="14" class="mr-1" />Norsk</MudSelectItem>
    </MudSelect>
</MudStack>

@code {
    private CultureInfo selectedCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    private CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("nb-NO"),
    };

    private async Task OnCultureChanged(CultureInfo newCulture)
    {
        if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture != newCulture)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(Navigation.Uri)
                .GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
            var cultureEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(newCulture.Name);
            var uriEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri);
            

            Navigation.NavigateTo(
                $"Culture/Set?culture={cultureEscaped}&redirectUri={uriEscaped}",
                forceLoad: true);
        }
    }
}

There are perhaps things I don't know which is probably obvious to how a StateHasChanged() should be used, but surely there are other steps I am missing or has gone over my head in how to prevent this from happening? Let me know if the information is lacking, and on what I can provide to help you understand the cause of the matter.
I've tried numerous things:

Set CultureInfo.CurrentCulture on controller. - I was expecting it to be able to change the culture on runtime, since it kept returning en-GB, but as i read through the web, its not how it works.
Set CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture - This actually solved the problem in a very bad way, as I understand it changes not just for the user but for everyone that accesses the page. And I could only call this through the setting method of the controller and the CultureSelector, and I had no idea how / where to access the cookie to then set the Culture if the website should suddenly restart.

I've tried other stuff too, but I felt like i never understood what I was truly doing to being able to properly explain it here.

I don't know why you need streamsubscriber etc. You can simply pass the culture code as a Url parameter use it straightaway. Also, see if removing that if and putting it outside InvokeAsync helps

The need for streamsubscriber was to simply push data from a grain to the page. And putting it outside the InvokeAsync doesn't update the data to the page (like realtime) like I wanted, should've probably put more context there.
But I did end up solving the problem as you both suggested that streamsubscriber "might" be the problem, so thank you anyways.

This is a commentary rather that an answer based on some educated guesswork.  I'm not sure that an answer is possible based on the information provided in the question [unless you are familiar with StreamSubscriber].
StreamSubscriber<DeviceStateEntry>.CreateAsync(...)

Registers a callback method with some type of reader.  StreamSubscriber will probably post the callback to the threadpool to execute on an available thread.  The culture of the executing thread will depend on how it does that, but it's likely to inherit the culture of the posting thread i.e. where the subscriber code that posted the callback ran.  The callback uses InvokeAsync to switch execution to the Synchronisation Context, but the culture of the invoking thread flows to the execution context on the Synchronisation Context: probably the default culture setting.
My guess is that the culture isn't set [or "passed" to] the thread running StreamSubscriber.  You've said that setting CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture solves the problem in a bad way.  What this probably does is set the culture of the thread running StreamSubscriber.
How to solve it?  Sorry don't know, as I'm unfamiliar with StreamSubscriber and how it works.

Shaun Curtis was dead-on point on why this was happening, it did not set nor pass the culture to the thread running the StreamSubscriber. So, upon inspecting the method which I originally didn't show:
public class StreamSubscriber<T> : IAsyncObserver<T>, IAsyncDisposable where T : class
    {
        private readonly Func<T, Task> _onDataReceived;
        protected StreamSubscriptionHandle<T>? SubscriptionHandle;

        public StreamSubscriber(Func<T, Task> onDataReceived)
        {
            _onDataReceived = onDataReceived;
        }

        public static async Task<StreamSubscriber<T>> CreateAsync(IClusterClient clusterClient, string ns, string key, Func<T, Task> OnDataReceived)
        {
            var subscriber = new StreamSubscriber<T>(OnDataReceived);

            var streamProvider = clusterClient.GetStreamProvider("StreamProvider");
            var stream = streamProvider.GetStream<T>(StreamId.Create(ns, key));
            subscriber.SubscriptionHandle = await stream.SubscribeAsync(subscriber);

            return subscriber;
        }

        public Task OnNextAsync(T item, StreamSequenceToken? token = null)
            => _onDataReceived(item);

        public Task OnCompletedAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
        public Task OnErrorAsync(Exception ex) => Task.CompletedTask;

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            if (SubscriptionHandle != null)
            {
                await SubscriptionHandle.UnsubscribeAsync();
                SubscriptionHandle = null;
            }
        }
    }

I made changes to where the methods were placed (now in the main project, instead of a shared referenced project) and then I added a local CurrentCulture onto the class. After further testing, this did indeed solve my problem. Final result of the StreamSubscriber is:
public class StreamSubscriber<T> : IAsyncObserver<T>, IAsyncDisposable where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<T, Task> _onDataReceived;
    protected StreamSubscriptionHandle<T>? SubscriptionHandle;
    private readonly CultureInfo _currentCulture;
    private readonly CultureInfo _currentUICulture;

    public StreamSubscriber(Func<T, Task> onDataReceived)
    {
        _onDataReceived = onDataReceived;
        _currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        _currentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    }

    public static async Task<StreamSubscriber<T>> CreateAsync(IClusterClient clusterClient, string ns, string key, Func<T, Task> onDataReceived)
    {
        var subscriber = new StreamSubscriber<T>(onDataReceived);

        var streamProvider = clusterClient.GetStreamProvider("StreamProvider");
        var stream = streamProvider.GetStream<T>(StreamId.Create(ns, key));
        subscriber.SubscriptionHandle = await stream.SubscribeAsync(subscriber);

        return subscriber;
    }

    public async Task OnNextAsync(T item, StreamSequenceToken? token = null)
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = _currentCulture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = _currentUICulture;
        await _onDataReceived(item);
    }

    public Task OnCompletedAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
    public Task OnErrorAsync(Exception ex) => Task.CompletedTask;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (SubscriptionHandle != null)
        {
            await SubscriptionHandle.UnsubscribeAsync();
            SubscriptionHandle = null;
        }
    }
}

Thank you for opening the third eye for me, it makes much more sense now.

NP.  Glad to be of assistance.  Real problem solving is about understanding the root cause: my commentary just helped you find it.
